# how to use two variables in for loop?

Tags: python

Define a function calls addFirstAndLast(x) that takes in a list of numbers and returns the sum of the first and last numbers.

Examples

```
>>> addFirstAndLast([])
0
>>> addFirstAndLast([2, 7, 3])
5
>>> addFirstAndLast([10])
10
```

---

My question is this that i can not use two variables in for loop, so what should i do , how to fix the error. and what could be the improved code of this problem.

---

```
def addFirstAndLast(x): 
    total = 0
    total1 = 0
    total2 = 0
    pos_last = []
    for num, last in x:
        num = str(num)
        num = num[0]
        total1 += int(num)
        last = last % 10
        pos_last = pos_last.append(last)

        total = sum(pos_last)
        total2 = total+total1
    return total2

print addFirstAndLast([2, 7, 3])
```

Comment: I'm still puzzled about... why do you need a loop ?

Comment: Hint: You don't want a `for` loop here. You have 3 distinct cases: 1) the list is empty, 2) the list has one element, 3) the list has two or more elements. You can use an `if...elif...else` block to handle these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 distinct cases: 1) the list is empty, 2) the list has one element, 3) the list has two or more elements.

Try without loop:

```
def addFirstAndLast(x):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(x) < 2:
        return x[0]
    else: 
        return x[0]+x[-1]

>>> print addFirstAndLast([2, 7, 3])
5
>>> print addFirstAndLast([2, 3])
5
>>> print addFirstAndLast([3])
3
```

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a list of integers, when using `x` in a for loop , each iteration would get a single integer. But when you do -

```
for num, last in x:
```

You are trying to unpack a single integer into 2 places, this cannot happen, and it is causing your issue.

I am not even sure what the rest of your logic does , you can do this simply using -

```
def addFirstAndLast(x):
    l = len(x)
    return x[0] + x[-1] if l > 1 else x[0] if l > 0 else 0
```

Examples -

```
>>> addFirstAndLast([])
0
>>> addFirstAndLast([2, 7, 3])
5
>>> addFirstAndLast([10])
10
```

---

Explanation of the logic - The expression is -

```
((x[0] + x[-1]) if l > 1 else x[0]) if l > 0 else 0
```

It first checks the outer most `if` condition, if length is 0 it returns 0 , if not it goes onto inner `if` condition.

In the inner `if` condition, if length is greater than 1(meaning there are 2 or more elements) it returns sum of first and last, otherwise (which means length is greater than 0 but less than 2 , meaning its 1) it returns first element.

Comment: thanks , it worked and yes thanks for clearing something i didn't know.

Comment: i did it , but i don't have enough reputation  to rate :D